# New Jersey 2014 senate votes by municipality?

Tags: united-states, election, senate, data-sources, new-jersey

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/2014_NJ_US_Senate_results_by_muni.svg

I was not able to find the vote total for this town. I live in New Jersey and I want to see the vote increase for the Democrat in my town from 2018 to 2014. What was the vote total for each municipality in the state? I want all of them so I could find it without giving out more than the state I live in.

Answer (score 4):

Municipality level breakdowns for New Jersey can be found directly from the NJ Division of Elections, [here](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/election-information-2014.shtml) for 2014, and [here](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/election-information-2018.shtml) for 2018. You can select your county and see the results for each municipality within it.

For example, for [Atlantic County](https://www.state.nj.us/state/elections/assets/pdf/election-results/2014/2014-us-senate-gen-elec-results-by-county-atlantic.pdf) in 2014:

[image]